# Return a variable value to to workspace before function ends

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am running a simulink simulation through a matlab function ,  the function assign's the slx files values for its blocks and based on the output of the simulation it calculates something and sends an output, now the problem is that the variable values assigned to the blocks are local to the function and do not appear on the workspace but the slx files needs variables in the workspace like for example

```
   function [return_result] = Test_Function(variablevalues1,variablevalues2)
   for i =1:length(variablevalues1)
       variable1 = variablevalues1(i);
       variable2 = variablevalues2(i);
       %do some calculation based on the result
       return_result(end+1) = calculations
   end
   endfunction
```

so now i want to assign `variable1` `variable2` value to be assigned to the simulink blocks at each iteration, is there anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[assignin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)" function is particularly useful for exporting data from a function to the MATLAB workspace.